# Sass error active admin in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, activeadmin

I trying to run my server but I have always the same error... I dont find the solution. I search in github and on google nothing work...

Do you have idea ?

```
rails s
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'sass-rails'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Sass::Script
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails/helpers.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass/rails.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-rails-5.0.6/lib/sass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
/home/nicolas/Bureau/rails/site/campsite/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
/home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
    from /home/nicolas/Bureau/rails/site/campsite/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
    from /home/nicolas/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

My gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
#gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
#Recherche
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'
gem 'elasticsearch-model'
gem 'searchkick'
#Pagination
gem 'kaminari'
#Google map
gem 'gmaps4rails'
#Gem pour faciliter les scopes des recherches
gem 'has_scope'
gem 'record_tag_helper', '~> 1.0'
#Upload d'images
gem 'carrierwave'
#activeadmin
gem 'sass-rails'

gem 'activeadmin', '~> 1.0.0.pre4'
gem 'inherited_resources', :git => "https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources.git"
gem 'ransack',             :git => "https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack.git"
gem 'draper',              '> 3.x'
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancancan'
gem "rolify"
# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'gmaps-autocomplete-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
#geocoder
gem 'geocoder'
#ImageUploader
gem "paperclip"
#friendly url
gem 'friendly_id'
#balise SEO
gem 'meta-tags'
#bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
#Traduction
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 5.0.0' # For 5.0.x
#mailboxer
gem 'mailboxer', :git => "https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer.git"
#uploadimage
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'

#gem 'inherited_resources', :git => "https://github.com/activeadmin/inherited_resources.git"

gem "font-awesome-rails"

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

If you need more details I can paste my other file. Just ask me ;)

EDIT
Gist link [Here](https://gist.github.com/nicolaswecandoit/492e6df130833d8db037413e3b80b1ef)

Comment: Have You tried using sprockets-sass instead? It has a lot more features including a cache store and a compressor and also has suport for other preprocessors or transformers .   However related to your question it seems the master branch of sass-rails does not have the helpers module anymore.  I suggest You to try out the master branch and see how that goes .

Comment: How I can do that ? Do you any example ?

Comment: Not sure if You are asking about sass-rails or the other one. However for sass-rails You can specify in Gemfile `gem 'sass-rails', git: 'git@github.com:rails/sass-rails.git' ` .  If You are referring though to sprockets-sass . You can find that informațion on the readme https://github.com/petebrowne/sprockets-sass .  Basically for rails You just need to add it to Gemfile then specify in your environment file ( development,production,etc) `config.css_compressor= :sprockets_sass' ( for sprockets 3.x ) . The gem currently supports only sprockets 2.x and 3.x. Sprockets 4.x is not yet supported

Comment: However support for sprockets 4.x will be added soon. ( Disclaimer: i worked on support for sprockets 3.x and i will probably work on the sprockets 4.x too very soon )

Comment: Forgot to mențion for sass-rails after You update the Gemfile You  need to run 'bundle install' again

Comment: Also it seems my above comment with the disclaimer can be a bit confusing. I wanted to say i worked on support for sprockets 3.x for sprockets-sass gem and that i am currently working on adding support for sprockets 4.x.

Comment: Hope this helps :)

Comment: @RadaBogdan Thanks for your help, I tryed to implement sass-rails with github link and I have same error. I tryed to implement sprockets-sass and same error too... I m lost :(

Comment: Can You try please requiring sass gem BEFORE requiring sass-rails or sprockets-sass?

Comment: And make sure You are requiring it also before sprockets

Comment: @RadaBogdan I need one more gem to use sass-rails gem ? It's strange cause  that's work on C9.io but not on my VirtualBox Antergos... I m lost, sorry for nooby attitude

Comment: Yes. You need to add sass to your Gemfile before You require these other gems

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129665/discussion-between-nicolaswecandoit-and-rada-bogdan).

Comment: I left a comment în the chat. Please check and get Back to me in the chat. Thanks

Comment: Hey @RadaBogdan I left a reponse on this place too ;)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have replied there . I am really Glad it works now on Ubuntu.  Let me know if this is still needs further investigation for Argento. I suspect you have there both RVM and system ruby installed. Maybe deleting the system ruby will.fix your problem. I had kinda same issue a while Back on my machine .

Comment: I have finally made the test application run on Antergos OS . Please see chat for details.

Comment: The problem you had has caused by having both RVM and a system ruby with same version installed, and bundler was not very happy about it. 
 if you run the Vagrant configuration i have sent you on chat, the application works good, if you use RVM properly.